# Yatch: panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: docker

I am learning Yacht https://github.com/SelfhostedPro/Yacht via https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GUfN1Fn38Kk

I am using Windows 10 x64, Docker Desktop for Windows 4.10.1 (82475). My command

```
docker run -d -v C:/tempvy:/var/run/docker.sock containrrr/watchtower:latest --cleanup --run-once yatchvy
```

error

```
time="2022-07-14T06:54:15Z" level=info msg="Watchtower 1.4.0"
time="2022-07-14T06:54:15Z" level=info msg="Using no notifications"
time="2022-07-14T06:54:15Z" level=info msg="Only checking containers with name \"yatchvy\""
time="2022-07-14T06:54:15Z" level=info msg="Running a one time update."
time="2022-07-14T06:54:15Z" level=error msg="Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?"
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x28 pc=0x953ba6]

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/containrrr/watchtower/pkg/metrics.NewMetric(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /home/runner/work/watchtower/watchtower/pkg/metrics/metrics.go:31 +0x26
github.com/containrrr/watchtower/cmd.runUpdatesWithNotifications(0xc00040b730, 0x0)
        /home/runner/work/watchtower/watchtower/cmd/root.go:379 +0x1b7
github.com/containrrr/watchtower/cmd.Run(0xc0000bfb80, 0xc000462120, 0x1, 0x3)
        /home/runner/work/watchtower/watchtower/cmd/root.go:175 +0x819
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0xc0000bfb80, 0xc0000300d0, 0x3, 0x3, 0xc0000bfb80, 0xc0000300d0)
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.0.0/command.go:846 +0x2c2
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0xc0000bfb80, 0x406325, 0xc000080058, 0x0)
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.0.0/command.go:950 +0x375
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(...)
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.0.0/command.go:887
github.com/containrrr/watchtower/cmd.Execute()
        /home/runner/work/watchtower/watchtower/cmd/root.go:71 +0x31
main.main()
        /home/runner/work/watchtower/watchtower/main.go:13 +0x25
```

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't support Windows:

> Currently only linux has been verified as working but we are open to
> the idea of supporting windows eventually as well.